# Will the result of HTTPS and SSH encryption of the same data be identical for two separate requests?

Tags: encryption, tls, ssh

If I was to request an image over HTTPS and record the packets over WireShark and then inspect a peer's Wireshark and look for the same packets, would I be able to see if they requested the same file, whether it's at the same host or a different one?

Comment: Question headline appears misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The session key under which the data is actually encrypted is derived randomly.

Comment: is this for both HTTPS and SSH?

Comment: Yes, it's true for all competently-written crypto.